# "Protected" error when using "new_copy_url"

Tags: box-api

I have developed a Box App using "Web App Integrations", the options to manage the file from Box web using right click on it.

It is a popup integration that gets the file modify it and save it again.
Some time ago we detected it was broken but have not had time to check it until now and the problem lays in our last request to box when we want to save the modified file.

In our callback we are requesting #overwrite_url# and #new_copy_url# and we post to that urls with the modified files to "save as" or "save" based on user selection.

The new documentation does not describe this 2 parameters but the app management allows them to be requested so I assume that they are not deprecated, other than that I have not been able to see a difference in the documentation related to this issue.

The request we are using is:

```
POST /api/1.0/new_copy/dmq5esykpq30sp2kepy3b1d7mvese5ap/9721827325?new_file_name=Koala.proton.jpg HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=2iqAzMZWpgN473oDBmRGnysbfTtsD2
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
User-Agent: Java/1.7.0_45
Host: upload.box.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 17831

--2iqAzMZWpgN473oDBmRGnysbfTtsD2
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="empty.dat"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 17627
```

And the only response I get is a 200 response with the body "restricted" without further information.

I suspect this has something to do with the deprecation of APIv1 but the integrations does not use the api and I did ask a couple of times to box support mail if the deprecation was going to have some effect to integrations and the responses were always negative.

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely changes required in order to update your integration to continue to work.  Yes, V1 APIs have been deprecated, and so your old integration has stopped working.

New documentation is [here](https://developers.box.com/box-web-application-integrations/) .  Subtle difference is that you get way more power now for these web-app integrations.  Tokens don't expire after 24 hours, but follow Box's same OAuth2 rules. Scope of your token will be for the file or folder that your web-app-integration is invoked on.

Fundamentally, first step after you get the inbound request on your server is to trade in the auth_code for an Auth-Token via the OAuth2 endpoints.

See the section on auth_code. Then you will have an Auth-token that will let you call regular V2 APIs.  To do a copy you would then :

```
POST https://api.box.com/2.0/files/{id}/copy  (with the Bearer-token header)
```

See https://developers.box.com/docs/#files-copy-a-file for the documentation on how to do a copy operation.  Nice thing is you can also do any number of other API calls with that token... as long as they are within scope of that file.

Comment: So #overwrite_url# and #new_copy_url# are deprecated and their return value are not useful anymore? Previously those values returned a url that didn't needed a token. I am doubtfull because those parameters are still offered in the app configuration and return a value as before.

Comment: I have tried to use the #auth_code# and I can trade it and do a file info request but the parent on the file info returns as null and upload calls fails. I am using BOX java SDK to do the calls, you can see the traces at http://pastebin.com/eVg06kdG

Comment: The token you have, by default, is only good for the object (file or folder) that it was granted for.  If you need to modify the parent, then you need to send a support ticket to api@box.com and ask to have your web-app-integration upgraded to have parent access.

Comment: What we were doing is reading a file, editing it and saving the file again as a new file or overwriting it (with a different extension). Think of it like watermarking an image or signing a document. 
I don't think that's modifying the folder, maybe for the "save as" but I will send an email to check it

Comment: If you are just saving the file back at the same location, then you just need a normal file-object scoped token.  You won't need parent-item access.